Load Image without update the app Android
I want to develop my Android Studio application using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose for the UI, but I've been stuck for a while on the topic of adding a dynamic image to my app. Specifically, I want to include an image that I can change at any time without requiring the user to update the app.
However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this. One idea I have is to use a website to host my images and retrieve their URLs to directly embed them into my code. While this should work, the issue is that the image URLs will constantly change, so I'm unsure how to proceed. If you could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

You don't change the URL.  When you want to change the image, you upload the new image to the same URL as the old one, deleting the old one.  Then the next time the app attempts to load the URL, they get the new image.

The URL won't change? So, if I upload my first image to an online site, when I want to change the image, I just need to delete the first image and replace it with my second image? Logically, this would modify the URL because the image is no longer the same, right? Do you have any websites for hosting images to do what you're saying, "upload the new image to the same URL as the old one"?

No the url will not change if you keep the same file name.

@FREERIKK depends on the place where you upload your files, a regular web hosting site doesn't change urls when you simply replace files. Files on Github for example are also available using stable urls. Sites like imgur, google drive, etc don't allow that.If you need to upload large amounts of data to places that don't have stable urls you can still do that but you would need to have like a text or json file that contains all the dynamic urls uploaded to a place that doesn't change urls.

@zapl I think there is something i don't understand, you say in Github I can have static file but I've try to set my Image in but I can't replace them, the link change, I've try Imgur but when I replace the image the link add a ?1 and more when it's not the first replace
Do you have the name of a hosting site for my image ?

@FREERIKK for github for example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/kotlin/master/ReadMe.md - if you modify that ReadMe.md file and just push a new version to the master branch, you don't have to change the url to that file, the content changes to whatever is the current state in the master branch. Theres also GitHub Pages you could have a look at. Alternatives are things like GoDaddy or for small projects the free plan of google's firebase hosting https://firebase.google.com/products/hosting - limited to 360MB/day traffic should be enough for testing

Just reserve one folder on your website where you put all images in.
Make a .php script that can list the files in that folder.
You only have to cast in concrete in your app the url of that .php script.
